# When attemping to copy a dir from repo to container in workflow, it's as if COPY command did nothing

Tags: dockerfile, github-actions

My repo:

```
/   
  dbt-action/
    action.yml
    Dockerfile
    entrypoint.sh
    dbt/
      profiles.yml
```

My workflow step:

```
  - name: Run DBT
    uses: ./dbt-action
```

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM ghcr.io/dbt-labs/dbt-redshift:1.3.latest
COPY dbt .dbt
COPY entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
```

My entrypoint:

```
!/bin/bash
pwd
ls -la
```

Outputs the following:

```
drwxr-xr-x 6 1001  123 4096 Jan  7 13:06 .
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root 4096 Jan  7 13:06 ..
drwxr-xr-x 8 1001  123 4096 Jan  7 13:06 .git
drwxr-xr-x 3 1001  123 4096 Jan  7 13:06 .github
drwxr-xr-x 3 1001  123 4096 Jan  7 13:06 blah
-rw-r--r-- 1 1001  123 1744 Jan  7 13:06 README.md
drwxr-xr-x 3 1001  123 4096 Jan  7 13:06 dbt-action
```

Expected output:

Same as above but with additional directory `.dbt` coming from `COPY dbt .dbt` in my Dockerfile.

Why don't I see dir .dbt when I ls -la in my entrypoint?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are executing your ‘Docker build’ from the wrong working directory, since the ‘dbt-action’ folder is present, but not it contents. Can you double check the PWD before you build?

Comment: Hi Rob. The pwd output is `/github/workspace`. Github actions seems to have it's own logic and rules around working dir and home. I expected that since the action.yml file inside the dbt-action dir is where the image is, everything would be built relative to that dir, but it looks not to be the case. I think this issue is distinct to Github actions paths/dirs.